# Not quite understanding proof of theorem 2, section 58 of Halmos' Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

The proof of theorem 2 of section 58 (Jordan Form) of Halmos' Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces says the following (this is near the end of the first paragraph in page 114):

> Since the only proper values of $A$ on $M_j$ is $\lambda_j$, and since $A$ on $N_j$ doesn't have the proper value $\lambda_j$ (that is, $A - \lambda_j$ is invertible on $N_j$), it follows that the dimension of $M_j$ is exactly $m_j$ and that each of the subspaces $M_j$ is disjoint from the span of all others.

I'm wondering why that last statement is true:

> and that each of the subspaces $M_j$ is disjoint from the span of all others

I can't follow it. On my own, I managed to prove that any two $M_i$ and $M_j$, with $i \ne j$, are disjoint. However, I couldn't manage to prove that $M_j$ is disjoint from the span of all others, which is the sum of all those other subspaces.

Can anyone shed any light on this? I'm sort of stuck on this for about three days.

Comment: What is the sum of the dimensions of these subspaces?

Comment: Each subspace M_i has dimension m_i. And if you add all of them, you get the dimension of the containing vector space. But how does that help? I imagine I'll need to make use of the dimensions later, to prove that (once I know about the disjointness) these subspaces add up to form the enclosing vector space.

Comment: Yeah, I was going the wrong way with that. Is $M_i$ is the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$?

Comment: I've never had seen the definition of generalized eigenspace before, but it seems like they are from what I've seen right now! In fact, one of the things I have is a proof that (e_i*Ident - A) restricted to M_i is nilpotent where e_i is an eigenvalue of A.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way to show that $M_j$ is disjoint from the span of the other $M_i$.

Suppose we have $v_1+\cdots+v_d=0$, where $v_i\in M_i$. Let $A_i=A-\lambda_iI$ and $r_i$ such that $A_i^{r_i}v_i=0$. Set $S=A_2^{r_2}\cdots A_d^{r_d}$. Then $Sv_i=0$ for $i\ge 2$, so $Sv_1=0$.

Now, suppose that $v_1\ne0$. Consider the sequence $$
v_1,\, A_dv_1,\dots,A_d^{r_d}v_1,\,A_{d-1}A_d^{r_d}v_1,\dots,\, A_{d-1}^{r_{d-1}}A_d^{r_d}v_1,\dots,\, A_2^{r_2}\cdots A_d^{r_d}v_1=Sv_1.
$$
$M_1$ is invariant under each of the $A_i$ in this sequence, so each vector in this sequence is an element of $M_1$. Since $Sv_1=0$, there is a vector $w\ne 0$ in this sequence such that $A_iw=0$ for some $i\ge2$, i.e., $w\in \ker A_i$, but this is impossible since the eigenspaces are pairwise disjoint. Therefore, $v_1=0$ and, by symmetry, all of the $v_i$ are $0$.

There’s probably a more straightforward proof, but I’d have to take a look at Halmos’ proof again to find it.

Comment: I think I did it. For all $v$ in the intersection of $M_j$ and the span of all others, call that set $X_j$, ${A_i}^{m_i}v = 0$, which means the minimal polynomial $m$ for A restricted to $X_j$ (such operator exists because $X_j$ is A-invariant) divides $(x-\lambda_i)^{m_i}$. But it's also true that the product of ${A_j}^{m_j}$ for all $j \ne i$ applied to $v$ is also 0 for all v in $X_i$. Then, $m$ also divides the polynomial $(x-\lambda_1)^{m_1}(x-\lambda_2)^{m_2}...{(x-\lambda_{j-1})^{m_{j-1}}}
{(x-\lambda_{j+1})^{m_{j+1}}}...(x-\lambda_r)^{m_r}$, thus $m = 1$ and $X_i = \{0\}$

Comment: I'm going to do something else in here. I'll go back to linear algebra studying later, and then I'll read your proof. Once you mentioned the notion of generalized eigenspaces, I went to look up the concept, and then I had this idea I just wrote about. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Also, in my above sketch of a proof, I was using the letter $r$ for the number of distinct eigenvalues $A$ has, but I should be using $p$, which is what the book uses.

Comment: Your proof looks good, too. No particular reason to use $p$ since this result stands on its own as a property of eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues. Note that the key step in both proofs is the same: you construct a linear map that has $M_j$ as an invariant and all of the other $M_i$ in its kernel.